# Class copy construction can't have parameter of type of the class

Tags: c++, class

```
class test{
     test(test);
     //test(test*);
};
```

I'm curious why c++ forbid having parameter of type of the class in construction function.
Is it very hard for compiler to deal with?

Comment: Copy ctor is test(test const&)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it would generate a recursive constructor. When you pass by value, it needs to copy construct the parameter before it passes it...which calls `test(test)`, which needs to...you get the picture.

You need to pass by reference for a copy constructor: `test(const test& rhs)`.

Answer (score 4):

When you pass a parameter by value, it's copied. So for the parameter to passed by value into the copy constructor, it must be copied. But the copying mechanism is what you're in the middle of defining. So how do you copy without being able to copy?

You can't, therefore the copy constructor cannot accept by value (hence `test(const test& t)` rather than `test(test t)`).

Answer (score 2):

Because of infinite recursion. You pass the original object by value in the constructor, therefore it should be copied using the same constructor you are calling.